# invalid column name 'Pediatri'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Why this happen? this column name on my table is ok, can y give me an idea please?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("select Emri from Drsignup WHERE Departamenti=" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value + " ", cn);
            SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet det = new DataSet();
            dt.Fill(det);
            DropDownList4.DataSource = det;
            DropDownList4.DataTextField = "Emri";
            DropDownList4.DataBind();
```

Comment: missing single quotes, without the single quotes SQL consider it's a column name and not a string literal

Comment: Is 'Pediatri' a value in the drop-down list? Doesn't it need to be surrounded by quotes to be used in the where clause: WHERE Deparamenti = 'Pediatri'?

Comment: Mandatory link: http://xkcd.com/327/ . Please use parametrized queries. Stop that pain.

Comment: has you read about sql inject attacks btw?

Comment: yes is "Pediatri" a value in the dropdownlist

Comment: Since you're building your SQL query from user input, that query could be anything.  You should debug and see the *actual query* that you're executing if you want to resolve any errors with that query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a string value in your SQL query without enclosing it in quotes:

```
select Emri from Drsignup WHERE Departamenti=Pediatri
```

So the SQL engine thinks `Pediatri` refers to a database object (in this case a column).

You *could* wrap it with quotes, but that only temporarily solves this one symptom of the problem.  The problem itself is that you're concatenating input to the query as code instead of treating it as a value.  Instead, use a parameter for the value:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("select Emri from Drsignup WHERE Departamenti = @Departamenti", cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Departamenti", DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value);
```